# Not getting token from ionic push.register when debug mode is false

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, apple-push-notifications, ionic2

I am implementing push notification in my ionic app.

I have setup initial steps successfully. In mu debug mode When I use this code:

```
     $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    var push = new Ionic.Push({
        "debug": true,
      "onNotification": function(notification) {
      var payload = notification.payload;
      console.log(notification, payload);
      }
    });

    push.register(function(token) {
                  alert("Hello");
        console.log("Device token:",token.token);
        });
    });
```

I have already run this command:

```
    ionic config set dev_push true
```

I am getting device token value and receiving push `successfully`.

But when I run this command

```
   ionic config set dev_push false
```

and put `"debug": true,` I am not receiving any token.

I have successfully uploaded the `.p12` file in Online Acccount of ionic.

Comment: ` ionic config set dev_push false` is to disable limited push

Answer (score 0):

If you set dev_push false. You won't get a notification.
Reason.
The variable is named as development_push meaning it is to be used in development mode only. Which means you are on a laptop/PC and testing the API in development mode. But if you switch to, `development_push = false` then it means you ain't testing on a system anymore and you need to put that .apk or ios equivalent in your phone and test it out in the real world.
So If I were you.
I would set it to false
Build my application.
and install the app in my phone.
and see if it works.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

After spending one complete day. I found one simple solution.

I don't know whether it will work for others or not. But still I am posting may be it helps someone.

After changing:

```
  ionic config set dev_push true
```

to

```
  ionic config set dev_push false
```

You have to first remove the `Platform` whether it is `iOS/Android.`

```
  ionic platform rm ios/androind
```

Then add again and build your project. Now it will work for sure.

```
  ionic platform add ios/android
  ionic build ios/android
```